# Adding Auto Increment Value to Column in relation to Duplicate values in Another Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large table (3 million rows and about 12 columns).  I have one column that can contain duplicate values - this is my "ID" column.  I have a second column "NUM_ID" that I would like to have it start at the value of 1 for every unique "ID".  Then - if I run into a duplicate value - "NUM_ID" would then bump up one value (to 2) and so on.  For example:

```
ID     NUM_ID
1        1
2        1
2        2
2        3
3        1
3        2
4        1
5        1
5        2
5        3
5        4
```

Again, "ID" is pre-populated, I cannot change this column and its values.  My "NUM_ID" column is currently empty - I'm hoping there is a sql command I can use to populate the column as shown above?  I've tried using Python but updating 3M rows is taking a long time.  Also, if it matters, I am using PostGresSQL.

Help?  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, if you're using postgresql, you probably should remove mysql and sql-server from your tag list.

Comment: Rather than adding a column to the table here, I think you would be better with a view that uses `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY whatever)` for NUM_ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are Using `SQL Server` then You Should Use `ROW_NUMBER()` as below :

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) NUM_ID FROM #TM
```

**Result :**

```
ID  NUM_ID
1   1
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   1
3   2
4   1
5   1
5   2
5   3
5   4
```

Comment: How do I write this to the actual column "NUM_ID"?

Comment: i think you don't need to do this.

Comment: I would like to convert the two columns into a Primary Key (ID,NUM_ID) - which is why I'm hoping to populate the column.

Comment: Just in case anyone is curious - I solved this by creating a new table and then just copying the column.  Thanks @Yogesh Sharma